# Proving an alternating series is greater than 0

Tags: calculus

I wish to show that a series of the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot a_{n}\cdot f\left(x,\ n\right)$$
is greater than 0. The terms $a_{n}$ are complicated which makes the proof difficult. My idea was to choose a simpler $b_{n}$ which behaves similarly to $a_{n}$ in order to complete the proof. However, I was not sure if I should choose $a_{n}>b_{n}$ or $a_{n}<b_{n}$.
So my question is, if a series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot b_{n}\cdot f\left(x,\ n\right)>0$$ does it imply that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\cdot a_{n}\cdot f\left(x,\ n\right)>0$$
given that $a_{n}>b_{n}$? Or is the opposite true?

If neither is correct, is there another way I can show that the alternating series is positive?

Comment: It depends on $f$. Please detail what $f$ is.

Comment: f(x)=$\frac{x!}{(x-n)!}$ @FShrike

Comment: It would be good to put it in your main post